# celery error using Python3.3

Tags: python, celery

I am using python3.3 and I installed celery3.0.17
When I Do

```
import celery
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\celery-3.0.17-py3.3.egg\celery\__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    from .__compat__ import recreate_module
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\celery-3.0.17-py3.3.egg\celery\__compat__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .local import Proxy
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\celery-3.0.17-py3.3.egg\celery\local.py", line 87, in <module>
    class Proxy(object):
ValueError: '__name__' in __slots__ conflicts with class variable
```

does anybody know a solution for this error?

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution.

Here is a link with a solution:
https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/1107
But I will explain what you must do.
you have to install the following 4 links from github

```
pip install -U https://github.com/celery/py-amqp/zipball/master
pip install -U https://github.com/celery/billiard/zipball/master
pip install -U https://github.com/celery/kombu/zipball/master
pip install -U https://github.com/celery/celery/zipball/master
```